# Azure AD App got the wrong user to authenticate

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have two azure tenants (Tenant A and Tenant B).

I have one registered app (App001) in tenant B with "Supported account types" set to "My organization only".

Here are steps to replicate the issue:

1. Log into Tenant A's portal (portal.azure.com) with account A001
2. Open new tab and try to log into app (App001). It doesn't prompt me to enter account B001 at all. It logs in with account A001 and get this error:
   AADSTS90072: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider '{A001's email domain}' does not exist in tenant '{Tenant A}' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'({App001's name}) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account

Getting this error is expected because the app's setting does not allow different tenant/directory's user to authenticate.

The question/problem is why it did not prompt me to enter accounts for Tenant B?
Any place I should take a look at the settings?

Comment: have you tried in a incognito browser mode?

Comment: Is your app using the tenant-specific authority? I.e. is it using e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id`?

Comment: Depending on how you configured the auth flow, the browser keeps the sessions alive all major browsers today share session between tabs. Most likely you are not being asked to login again, because the redirect to login.microsoftonline.com sees you already have a live session and immediately redirects you back to the application. You can check cookies for that domain, and follow the login flow in the browser network tab (just set preserve log to enable, so it keeps all the redirects)

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio with incognito browser mode, it works. That is it is a clean start (no cookie). But the question is why? It should prompt me for user name/password, isn't it? I have tried the same steps for other tenants, no problem at all. Looks like something to do with the setting of Tenant B or App001. Just don't know where/what to look for.

Comment: @juunas yes. it is using tenant/specific authority.

Comment: @sjkp I agree that the cookie will be applied to all alive tab (same type of browser/mode). But I don't have this issue to other tenant/app setup. It always prompts me to login if the {tenant-id} changed.

Comment: @ZhiyuanZhang I think it's a bug on MSFT side. I'm facing a similar problem with videoindexer.ai portal, it seems to be mixing my personal and business accounts

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Have you reported this to MSFT for this before?

Comment: yes, but for videoindexer only

Comment: I have asked a questions in social.msdn.microsoft.com. Will see if anybody can give hint or have a solution for this issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de3421fb-8a58-4a8c-96d4-0619a54104d0/application-doesnt-prompt-for-login-instead-it-use-the-account-from-different-azure-tenant-which?forum=azureappconfiguration

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Have they fix your problem? Can you share the solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your account A001 cookie has been used to lon into app (App001).

The error occours because app (App001) doesn't exist in your Tenant A.

You should log into app (App001) with an incognito window (or log out of account A001 firstly). And then you will be asked to type in your credential. Now you could use account B001 to login.

Comment: This isn't an issue for other tenants. (don't have to log off first)

Comment: @ZhiyuanZhang Please provide the urls when you open new tab and try to log into app (App001) for both the account A001 and account in "other tenants". (I mean the URL after the page redirect, not the URL you use to access the app (App001))

Comment: posted question here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/4502/application-doesnt-prompt-for-login-instead-it-use.html